# How to add additional animations in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, uiviewanimation

I have the following code for my iPhone app in Xcode 4.5:

```
 [UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                duration:5.0f
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.view = self.view;
                } completion:NULL];
```

The code works exactly how I want except for 1 thing. Where I have self.view = self.view; I'd like a brief moment before this line where the view clears or even changes to nothing but a black screen, and then transition into the next loaded self.view. The reason is that some of my screens are very similar and the user might think the view didn't reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.view = self.view can not compose animation

set self.view.alpha to zero then do animations.

```
self.view.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
                  duration:5.0f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
                } completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This code doesn't do anything different from what I had (At least noticeable/visual things). I tried alpha equal to a bunch of different combinations, but I think I'm satisfied with my original post. Thanks!